# Interesting way to catch all Rebol VID errors

Tags: rebol, rebol2

I stumbled on this and just wanted to make sure this isn't a glitch in Rebol's design. I have the following code which seems to successfully catch all program errors in the VID environment.

```
view layout [ 
    across    
    label  "Rebol Command:" 
    f: field [
       do f/text 
       focus f     
    ] return 
    button "Error 1" [
        print this-is-an-error-1
    ]
    button "Error 2" [
        print this-is-error-2
    ]

    time-sensor: sensor 0x0 rate 1000 
    feel [
        engage: func [face action event] [
            if action = 'time [
                time-sensor/rate: none
                show face
                if error? err: try [
                    do-events
                    true ; to make the try happy
                ][
                    the-error: disarm :err 
                    ? the-error
                    ; reset sensor to fire again
                    time-sensor/rate: 1000
                    show face
                    focus f
                ]
            ]
        ] 
    ]
    do [
        focus f
    ] 
]
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a glitch—`do-events` is indeed the dispatcher that will run until an error occurs. I'd suggest decoupling the error handler from the layout model itself though:

```
view/new layout [ 
    across    
    label  "Rebol Command:" 
    f: field [
       do f/text 
       focus f     
    ] return 
    button "Error 1" [
        print this-is-an-error-1
    ]
    button "Error 2" [
        print this-is-error-2
    ]
    do [
        focus f
    ] 
]

forever [
    either error? err: try [
        do-events
    ][
        the-error: disarm :err 
        ? the-error
        focus f
    ][
        break
    ]
]
```

Comment: Great - thanks for clarifying this for me. This should make the graphic portion of my program way more robust.

Comment: What exactly is the advantage of running the forever loop separate from the layout? Other than clarity?

Comment: @dogeye Clarity is the main reason, yes. However you may also benefit from not engaging the event system 1000 times a second.